# Apache will not follow symlink without matching owner even with SymLinkIfOwnerMatch disabled?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, symlink

I am transferring some hosting accounts from CentOS 6 with Apache 2.2 to CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4.34. Some of these accounts symlink to files through a directory symlink *inside* the DocumentRoot to files *outside* the DocumentRoot.

Like this:

```
root:root /var/lib/common/html/
user:user /home/user/app/           => /var/lib/common/html/
user:user /home/user/html/file.html => /home/user/app/file.html
```

It works on Apache 2.2. On Apache 2.4 I get a 403 permission denied response. I can find no evidence that `SymLinkIfOwnerMatch` is set, only `FollowSymLinks` via grepping the config files. The 403 error goes away if I set the `/home/user/html/file.html` ownership to `root:root`. (Note that the "middleman" directory symlink ownership does not matter. Apache will follow it either way.)

Are there situations where Apache 2.4 will **always** require the symlink ownership to match? It seems that direct access, mod_rewrite, and even Alias are enforcing ownership matching and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The control panel I'm using provides a release of Apache with additional patches, and it also includes a `harden-symlinks.patch` file ([source](https://git.root.bg/root/apache-symlink-protection/blob/d9b66dd3cccc34441b91fd8528febc6f697212d2/harden-symlinks.patch)). The patch suggests an Apache `UnhardenSymLinks` option is available, but when I tried it apachectl errors with `Option UnhardenedSymLinks not allowed here`. I have tried it inside and outside the VirtualHost, inside a Directory, but it doesn't pass the config test anywhere.

After a little research, it looks like that patch is popular with most of the common hosting control panels. If you are using one, you are most likely using `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` even if you specify `FollowSymLinks` in your config.